# How to access attributes in sails.js model with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sails.js

I want to access some attributes in my edit view to change some values.

I've tried accessing with something like `<%=course.scoreAlgo=>` but that doesn't work.

I can't seem to access any of the attributes in my model inside the `script` tag. Any and all help how I can access this is greatly appreciated!

The course model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    code:{
      type: "string"
    },

    name:{
      type: "string"
    },

    recitations:{
      type: 'array',
      defaultsTo: 0
    },

    finishedAssignments:{
      type: "array"
    },

    recitationScore:{
      type: 'integer',
      defaultsTo: 0
    },

    recitationGroup:{
      type: "string",
      defaultsTo: "none"
    },

    shown:{
      type: "string",
      defaultsTo: "no"
    },

    scoreAlgo:{
      type:"array"
    },

    takes:{
      model: 'student'
    }
  }
};
```

And this is what the code I'm trying to make work looks like:

```
<form action="/course/update/<%= course.id %>" method="POST">
  <h2>Edit course</h2>
  <input value="<%= course.code%>" type="text" name="code"><br/>
  <input value="<%= course.name%>" type="text" name="name"><br/>
  <input value="<%= course.shown %>" type="text" name="shown"><br/>
  <input value="<%= course.recitationScore%>" type="text" name="recitationScore"><br/>
  <p>Score algo, specify by saying how many have to be completed for each "subgroup".
    If two from a, two from b and one from c means full score, put "2,2,1"</p>
  <input value="<%=course.scoreAlgo%>" type="text" name="scoreAlgo">
  <input type="button" value="Calculate recitationScore" onclick="calcScore()">
  <script>
    function calcScore(){
      var stringArray = course.finishedAssignments;
      var scoreAlgo = course.scoreAlgo;
      for(var i=0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
        var str = stringArray[i];
        var sStr = str.split(",");
        for(var j=0; j < sStr.length; j++){
          var count = scoreAlgo[i]
          var s = sStr[i];
          var sS = s.split((i+1).toString);
          if(sS.length >= count){
            var score = sS.length*33;
            course.recitationScore = course.recitationScore + score;
            console.log(score);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <input type="submit" value="Edit course"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All values you pass to .ejs and want to be displayed you need to wrap with `<%= %>` or `<%- %>` even in `<script></script>`

```js
function calcScore(){
  var stringArray = <%= course.finishedAssignments %>;
  var scoreAlgo = <%= course.scoreAlgo %>;
  for(var i=0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    var str = stringArray[i];
    var sStr = str.split(",");
    for(var j=0; j < sStr.length; j++){
      var count = scoreAlgo[i]
      var s = sStr[i];
      var sS = s.split((i+1).toString);
      if(sS.length >= count){
        var score = sS.length*33;
       //course.recitationScore = course.recitationScore + score; <!- not sure what should it do
        console.log(score);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But if I put the attributes inside `<%=%> then the variables aren't defined. It then says `stringArray variable might not be defined` for instance.

And the last bit that you commented is suppose to add len of sS times 33 to recitation score. Guess I could do `course.recitationScore+= len*33`?

Comment: Ok.. Because those are arrays you need to change them into JSON. <%- JSON.stringify(data) %> And you cannot update models in views like that. You can't use course as javascript param. If you really need it there you can do it like that: var course = <%- JSON.stringify(course) %>;

Comment: Okey, thanks.

So I can't update model attributes like that huh. Well that sucks, thought it'd be easy to it this way :)

Comment: Nope. You need to post data to model/controller/blueprint to update.

Comment: Okey, thank you for helping. This all seems like quite a bit of work. Anything I could do to make it easier/more simple?

Comment: You should rethink that update function and update it in database with ajax maybe.